# PiCamera pictures inconsistent

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am working with a Raspberry pi with a camera module (Raspberry pi Camera) mounted on a drone and programmed to take pictures after a fixed interval. However, the images seem to be a bit inconsistent as seen below [image].

Images 4 and 8 appear to have slightly more 'colored' as compared to other images and appear to have more saturation. However, as the default saturation is 0 and my code is not changing that, I believe it is something else. My python script is as below

```
def calibrate(t):
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
       time.sleep(t)
       camera.shutter_speed = camera.exposure_speed
       ss=camera.shutter_speed
       camera.still_stats = 'true'
       camera.exposure_mode = 'off'
       g = camera.awb_gains
       camera.awb_mode = 'off'
       camera.awb_gains = g
       camera.close()
       return ss,g

def capture(ss,g,stream):
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:           
       camera.resolution = (3280,2464)       
       camera.shutter_speed = ss
       camera.still_stats
       camera.exposure_mode = 'off'
       camera.awb_mode = 'off'
       camera.awb_gains = g
       camera.still_stats = 'true'
       camera.capture(stream,format='jpeg')
       camera.close()
```

I call the calibrate function before taking any pictures that calibrate the camera. After calibrating, I take the pictures and get this problem. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried it with `awb_mode` set to `'auto'`? It just looks like white balance problems to me, which might mean you are seeing slightly different lighting conditions in those frames. Setting it to auto might help with that, although I don't have any experience with PiCamera specifically and do not know how well it handles WB. For that matter, how does it look if you just take the intensity of each frame?

Comment: I'd also say you look a little overexposed. You might want to set `exposure_compensation` to -4 or -5 or so, just to see if you get more detail.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/api_camera.html):

> Enabling the still statistics pass will override fixed white balance
>   gains (set via awb_gains and awb_mode).

I would bet that `awb_mode` gets set back to something other than `off` when you change `still_stats`. Exact same problem seems to be reported [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=875772&sid=92fa4ea70d1fe24590a4cdfb4a10c489).

Comment: So I removed the still stats and the problem seemed to disappear, confirming that its a white balance problem (an auto-white balance causes this). However, when I take still stats off, I get the cyan vignetting problem with the camera (a well known problem in picamera). Is there any other way I can tackle both these problems?

Comment: I'm afraid I know almost nothing about cameras, so someone else will have to help you with that. I've never worked with a picamera yet either, just scoured the docs.